# HtmlUnit: one WebClient per thread - is it thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, htmlunit

I have many threads. Each thread creates and uses it's own WebClient (HtmlUnit framework). No one thread uses WebClient's instance from other thread. Is it thread safe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClient.html)

> Note: a WebClient instance is not thread safe. It is intended to be used from a single thread.

As long as each thread creates its own WebClient, you won't have any issues. From what you said, you're doing the right thing.